# React Page shows source code when page is refreshed in browser

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am admittedly new to React. I am creating my first real project after doing a tutorial, so it is entirely possible the issue is very easy to resolve. I am sure I am missing or ignorant of something basic.

I have an issue where I am rendering a component on a page, and when I first load the page or navigate to it via my navigation, it renders as I would expect. However, if I refresh the page, instead of rendering, it displays code on my page:

```
import { createHotContext as __vite__createHotContext } from "/@vite/client";import.meta.hot = __vite__createHotContext("/Roster.jsx");import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh";
let prevRefreshReg;
let prevRefreshSig;
if (import.meta.hot) {
  if (!window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__) {
    throw new Error("@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201");
  }
  prevRefreshReg = window.$RefreshReg$;
  prevRefreshSig = window.$RefreshSig$;
  window.$RefreshReg$ = (type, id) => {
    RefreshRuntime.register(type, "C:/Users/Me/Coding Projects/Hus Av Ulver/src/Roster.jsx " + id);
  };
  window.$RefreshSig$ = RefreshRuntime.createSignatureFunctionForTransform;
}
```

NOTE: this is on a localhost server, this is not deployed. I am not sure if this information is relevant, but thought I would provide it.

I am using Vite, and Browser Router. The only thing I have really tried is just making the component/page print a simple "Hello World!" div, just to see if there was anything in my component code that could possibly be throwing an error. This did not help.

I suspect the issue is something I am or am not doing correctly with browser router, but I've tried a lot of Googling with no success. I am hoping someone here can help me troubleshoot.